# "Simple Limit Argument" in Freitag's and Kiehl's Etale Cohomology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology, constructible-sheaves

I have a question about an argument used in Freitag's and Kiehl's [Etale Cohomology and the Weil Conjecture](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-662-02541-3) in the proof of:

**4.4 Lemma.** (p 41) Every sheaf $F$ representable by an étale scheme $U \to X$, i.e. for $ F(V)=\operatorname{Hom}_X(V, U)$ where $V \in \mathrm{Ét}/X$, is a constructible sheaf of sets.

*Proof:* In view of the criterion 4.3″ (…take it at this stage as a black box), it is enough to show that there is a nonempty étale scheme $W \to X$ for which the $W$-scheme $U \times_X W$ splits to $W \coprod W \coprod \dotsb \coprod W $.

For the proof we can assume that $X$ is integral (because $ \mathrm{Ét}(X)= \mathrm{Ét}(X_{\text{red}})$). If in particular $X$ is the spectrum of a field $k$, this statement means that for every finite separable field extension $K$ of $k$ there is a finite separable extension $L$ of $k$ such that

$$   L \otimes_k K = L \times L \times \dotsb \times L.  $$

The general case is reduced to this by a simple limit argument, taking $k $ specifically to be the function field of $X$.

**Question:** I do not understand concretely how the "simple limit argument" is carried out in detail reducing the general integral $X$ case to the case with $X$ spectrum of field as above. Could somebody elaborate this argument in detail?

Remark: Surely there exist other proofs of this lemma, but this question is focused only on the described reduction step from the quoted book.

Comment: Etale morphisms are not necessarily quasicompact (which is necessary for your argument), but they are filtering colimits of quasicompact etale morphisms.

Comment: @JasonStarr: right, I see. So to summarize, the argument boils down that scheme assoc to $K:= K(X)$ can be expressed as colimit of *quasicompact etale morphisms* and this quoted "simple limit argument" says that there exist one member in the colimit which inherits this splitting property which we showed above for $K$, that's the story?

Comment: #Add: More precisely, if I not missing something the argument should be work like that $K$ can be expressed as limit of rings $A_i$ whose assoc schemes $X_i$ are open and affine subschemes of $X$, whose colimit by construction is spec of $K$. And this "simple limit argument" seemingly uses  - at least if I understand it correctly- that there **exists** (...thats what presum the author meant exactly by this "limit argument") a member $X_j$ with desired property that canon proj $U \times_X X_j \to X_j $ has the properties we want:

Comment: quasicompact + etale + trivialization ... which in turn assures finiteness of of the fibres. Is the argument correct?

Comment: #Addendum: In second comment I wrote nonsense: *All* the members of the limit of course not neccessarily are etale! But as remarked in last comment it suffice that there *exist* one member with this property...